# Select words from a list such that the number of unique letters are minimum

Tags: algorithm, minimization

I have a list of words from which I have to select n words such that the number of the different/unique letters in them are kept to a minimum. I have a feeling that there's already a well known algorithm for this, but I'm not able to find it. Could point me to the algorithm that can be used to solve this?

### An example below to illustrate what I mean by unique letters

Say I have the list of words HELL, HELP and FAIL, and I have to select 2 words from them.

If I select HELL and HELP, the number of unique letters among them = 4

If I select HELL and FAIL, the number of unique letters among them = 6

If I select HELP and FAIL, the number of unique letters among them = 7

The algorithm should select HELL and HELP.

For my use-case, I expect there to be lists of about 15 words from which about 9 words would have to be selected.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for.. hashing? sets? In many languages that utilize sets, you can do fast comparisons between sets such as finding characters in one and not the other.

Comment: Given such small numbers, you can simply try out all possible combinations.

Comment: Even at the small numbers, the total number of combinations is 15!/(15-9)! which comes out to roughly 1.8 billion. There is likely an optimization with dynamic programming.

Comment: Oh I did permutations, it's more like 5000, that's more acceptable.

Comment: Still an exponential time, but if you are only doing 26 letters, that bit flag fits in an `uint32_t`. I have an intuition that this might be related to the minimum subset sum.

Answer (score 0):

Optimal solution can be found using a MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) model (or similar type of models).

Let i be the set of letters and w be the set of words. Furthermore, define binary variables:

```
x(w) = 1 if word w is selected 
       0 otherwise

y(i) = 1 if letter i is selected 
       0 otherwise
```

Then we can write:

```
min sum(i, y(i))
subject to
    sum(w,x(w)) = K
    y(i) >= x(w)  for letters i in word w
    y,z in {0,1}
```

When I solve this I see the following.

The data is organized as:

```
----      8 SET i  letters

A,    B,    C,    D,    E,    F,    G,    H,    I,    J,    K,    L,    M,    N,    O,    P,    Q,    R,    S,    T
U,    V,    W,    X,    Y,    Z


----      8 SET w  words

HELL,    HELP,    FAIL


----      8 SET map  

               A           E           F           H           I           L           P

HELL                     YES                     YES                     YES
HELP                     YES                     YES                     YES         YES
FAIL         YES                     YES                     YES         YES

----      8 PARAMETER k                    =        2.000  number of words to select
```

And the solution looks like:

```
----     29 VARIABLE x.L  select word

HELL 1.000,    HELP 1.000


----     29 VARIABLE y.L  selected letters

E 1.000,    H 1.000,    L 1.000,    P 1.000


----     29 VARIABLE z.L                   =        4.000  objective
```

MIP solvers are readily available.